# Which is the best approach to push an object into an array? - push(obj) or push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

There is a `users: any[] = []` array in my angular code which will be filled up dynamically with the person objects.

```
someMethod.subscribe((user) => {
  this.users.push(user);
})
```

But one of my colleagues preferred the below approach to push the object

```
someMethod.subscribe((user) => {
  this.users.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));
})
```

May I know - which would be the best approach & why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former. The latter is sometimes used to deep-clone an object, but if you're not modifying the objects in the array, there's no need. And it also carries some risks: you can lose some data that's not available in JSON, such as functions, regex, symbols, and undefined; you could end up with some altered data, like `NaN` becoming `null`, and it'll mess with dates depending on the date format. It's also slow (compared to methods from utility libraries): Financial Times did a writeup on their tech blog in 2018 showing that having a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...` on the data returned from every request slowed their site down by 10 times.

If you do need to clone the objects before pushing them, you could use a library like Lodash, or use `push({...user})`, depending on your exact needs.